# How to get figure onto same page as text

Tags: floats

I am writing a lab report introduction and am showing a figure of the reaction path. The image is very small and only requires the space of about 10 lines of text. However, when typesetting, Latex formats the figure so it is on a separate page, which looks very silly. How can I get the figure so be on the same page as the introduction paragraph?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}          
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\title{Experiment 3}

\author{Sophie Parsons%
  \thanks{CRSid: \texttt{bb70}}}
\affil{university}


\date{Dated: \today}

\maketitle



\section{Introduction}
In the reactor, the benzene and maleic anhydride can also degrade into other useless products, as shown in figure \ref{fig:7}.

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{scheme.pdf}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:7}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the `H` position specifier, as it may result in unwanted white spaces. Use `!htb` instead. This being said, try replacing the `center` environment (which adds a supplementary vertical spacing to the one added by the `figure`environment) with the `\centering` directive.

Comment: I have now done both these recommendations but it has moved my figure to the back of the report?

Comment: Then you should post a minimal example demonstrating the problem. Are you sure  your image is as small as it seems to be? It might have a bounding box much larger than the real image. You can test this using `\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{scheme.pdf}`.

Comment: you are right Bernard,the box fills the A4 page. However, I have now attached my image to the questions, and as you can see,  the actual image is much smaller. `\begin{figure}[!htb]
{\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{scheme.pdf}}
%\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{scheme.pdf}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:7}
}
\end{figure}`

Comment: Did you obtain this image  yourself, and if so, how?

Comment: The image is from my university's lab manual, which I obtained via "screenshot"

Comment: This means it's not a real .pdf file – I mean, when you zoom, the image has very bad quality, I guess? You have solutions: use some image viewer to crop it by hand, or use a LaTeX package to draw it (pstricks or TikZ) – this kind of drawing not hard to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your image you can generate with the following small document:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                chains,
                decorations.markings,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Triangle,
   decoration = {markings,% switch on markings
                 mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[thick]{>}}
                 },
     N/.style = {on chain},
node distance = 7mm and 21 mm,
    start chain = going right
                    ]
\node (a) [N]   {A};
\node (b) [N]   {B};
\node (c) [N]   {C};
%
\coordinate[below=of a] (aux);
\draw[postaction={decorate}]    (a) to ["$k_1$"]    (b);
\draw[postaction={decorate}]    (b) to ["$k_2$"]    (c);
\draw[postaction={decorate}]    (a) -- (aux) to ["$k_3$" '] (aux -| c) -- (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or include its code directly to your document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{tikz} % <--- added
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,         % <--- added
                chains,              % <--- added
                decorations.markings,% <--- added
                positioning,         % <--- added
                quotes,              % <--- added
                }

\begin{document}

\title{Experiment 3}
\author{Sophie Parsons%
  \thanks{CRSid: \texttt{bb70}}}
%\affil{university}
\date{Dated: \today}
\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
In the reactor, the benzene and maleic anhydride can also degrade into other useless products, as shown in figure \ref{fig:7}.
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering% <--- changed
        \begin{tikzpicture}[  % <--- added, instead of includegraphics
                > = Triangle,
       decoration = {markings,% switch on markings
                     mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[thick]{>}}
                     },
         N/.style = {on chain},
    node distance = 7mm and 21 mm,
        start chain = going right
                        ]
    \node (a) [N]   {A};
    \node (b) [N]   {B};
    \node (c) [N]   {C};
    %
    \coordinate[below=of a] (aux);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}]    (a) to ["$k_1$"]    (b);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}]    (b) to ["$k_2$"]    (c);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}]    (a) -- (aux) to ["$k_3$" '] (aux -| c) -- (c);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{default}
\label{fig:7}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and obtain:

[image]

note:

- instead of `tikz` package, you can use `pstric` (with latter i'm not familiar)
- image generated in separate document (its name is name of image, if you like to include as `.pdf` image) or with code by which you replace `\includegraphics{...}` hasn't spurious space around it. consequently it should be on the same page as they are inserted in text (with exception, that it is inserted till before bottom of page).
- i drown this image for fun and exercise. if you have question about `tikz`, don't hesitate to ask new questions ...